# Validation on DTO not working from non-controllers

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I have a request DTO, with nested objects as members, and one of them has an @Email validation on it.

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class MyRequest {

    @NotNull
    @ApiModelProperty(required = true)
    @Valid
    private MyContact myContact;

}
```

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class MyContact {

    @Valid
    private ContactDto representative;

    @Valid
    private ContactDto owner;

}
```

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Setter
public class ContactDto {


    @NotNull
    @ApiModelProperty(required = true, example = "johndoe@example.com")
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Email(message = "My error message")
    protected String email;


}
```

MyRequest is being used to take the response body from a controller.

```java
            @ApiParam(required = true, name = "My Request",
                      value = "My value")
            @Valid @RequestBody MyRequest myRequest
```

The email validation works fine with the controller.
However, I am using the objects of `MyRequest` at other places as well (non-controllers), where the validation is not done when an object is created with an invalid email.

Comment: Is @Valid annotation used wherever you are trying to use MyRequest ?

Comment: I have added @Valid to the parameter `MyRequest myRequest` in a method which is getting called in the code.

Comment: Also, I tried creating another class and added a field to it of type MyRequest, and then used this new class to capture the request of a controller, with @Valid in the controller parameter. There the validation in myRequest are working. But not directly as I mentioned in my previous comment.